# How can I upload an app to the play store to work only on certain rom?

Tags: java, android, google-play, cyanogenmod

I'm trying to upload an app to the Google Play but I'm trying to make it available only for devices running my android rom like Cyanogenmod did [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cyngn.cameranext&hl=en) and like MOTOROLA did [here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.motorola.camera&hl=en).

I know there is an option to limit your app for certain devices, but I want to limit my app to a certain rom.

How can I do it?

Comment: According to Android Police, [Cyanogen Camera is only available for certain devices](http://www.androidpolice.com/2014/10/13/cyanogen-camera-appears-play-store-remains-cm11s-exclusive/). Motorola is a device manufacturer, not a ROM modder. What evidence do you have that either of these, or anything else, is based upon a ROM, and not a device?

Comment: So, you say It's impossible?

Comment: I am saying that I am not aware of the Play Store offering a filtering by ROM feature, particularly considering that no ROM mod has successfully licensed the Play Store AFAIK.

Comment: So is there a way to exclude all devices from installing?

Comment: There is no point in having an app on the Play Store if nobody can install the app. Distribute the app yourself via your own Web site.

Comment: Is it possible to exclude all the devices so later I could include like 4 devices instead of excluding 1 by 1